# Change user password in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I created a user in PostgreSQL, gave it a password using:

```
alter user username with password 'new_password';
```

But when I try to login using phpPgAdmin, it keeps saying use/password incorrect, do I have to do something after alter password, like on MySQL where you have to run flush privileges?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, no flush is needed.  The response given to the client is intentionally vague, to avoid disclosing information to a presumed attacker.  Look in the database server's log file for a more complete error message.

Comment: All I see is Peer authentication failed, I edited the postgresql hba conf file and changed from trust to md5 for local (something I read somewhere), but still nothing, I can see the user(s) when i type \du, but I'm not able to login as them when I run `psql -U <username> -W`

Comment: Peer authentication and password authentication and trust authentication are all mutually incompatible.  Have you been reloading the server config after making changes?

Comment: I did restart the service, but nothing happened, it still doesn't let me login with any of the users.

Comment: If your pg_hba.conf does not list peer authentication but you are still getting peer authentication failure messages in the logs, then you edited the wrong pg_hba.conf, restarted the wrong PostgreSQL server, or are attempting to connect to the wrong server.